# Python sh module and git try to add more files then in command

Tags: python, git

I'm trying to automatically add files to an existing repository using the `sh` python module. The problems seems to be that the command run is trying to add more files then specified.

Here is the offending command:

```
sh.git("add", "-f" if args.add_force else '', '--', *to_add)
```

`to_add` is a list of files. Below you can that `to_add` indeed had a list of files in it.

And its output:

```
Adding modified files...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./update_member.py", line 182, in <module>
    sh.git("add", "-f" if args.add_force else '', '--', *to_add)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 769, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 330, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 334, in wait
    self._handle_exit_code(self.process.wait())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 348, in _handle_exit_code
    self.process.stderr
sh.ErrorReturnCode_128:

  RAN: '/usr/bin/git add  -- CDD/Cdd_Diag.c CDD/Cdd_Diag.h CDD/Cdd_StatisticFunctions.h EcuSupervisor/Yes_Measurement.c EcuSupervisor/Yes_Os.c RTE/Dispatcher.c RTE/E2EM.c'

  STDOUT:


  STDERR:
fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF in pylint_catch_to_ninja.html
```

I tried this in the python console and i got the same output.

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 28 2014, 01:34:03)
[GCC 4.8.3] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sh
>>> sh.git('add', '', '--', 'CDD/Cdd_Diag.c')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 769, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 330, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 334, in wait
    self._handle_exit_code(self.process.wait())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 348, in _handle_exit_code
    self.process.stderr
sh.ErrorReturnCode_128:

  RAN: '/usr/bin/git add  -- CDD/Cdd_Diag.c'

  STDOUT:


  STDERR:
fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF in pylint_catch_to_ninja.html
```

The command printed under `RAN:` runs fine when i paste it into my shell.

Anyone got any idea on what could be going on?

Comment: I don't know how `sh` works, but you pass in an empty argument with `"-f" if args.add_force else '',` - maybe that confuses git.

Comment: @tdelaney Ok it's time I go home. That was it. Thank you.

Comment: @tdelaney If you provide that as an answer i'll tick it off.

Comment: Surely, this error 'fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF in pylint_catch_to_ninja.html' needs also to be fixed first. That is, ensure that those warnings are not given. The CRLF problem can be awkward to resolve (i.e. set a clear understandable policy and the config settings that will support it, and the staff believe ;-)

Comment: @PhilipOakley The problem is not the CRLF message, i know where that comes from and how to fix it. The problem is that the message about the CRLF is for a a file i was not trying to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each parameter to sh.git becomes an argument to git itself. When `add_force` is False, `"-f" if args.add_force else '',` adds an empty argument which confuses git. When you build up a command with optional arguments, you can just brute force it.

```
cmd = ["add"]
if args.add_force:
    cmd.append("-f")
cmd.extend(to_add)
sh.git(*cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimentation suggests that "git add ''" has the same effect as "git add .".  This accounts for the effect "the message about the CRLF is for a a file i was not trying to add" -- Git thought you were trying to add it.